# Conditions in usercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, user-controls

let's say I have a user control with dropdowns/textboxes/gridviews etc.
All of this is controlled by a parameter(or several parameters)

let's say I'm adding my usercontrol to a page and set something like:

```
userControl1.Type = Advanced;
```

Or

```
userControl1.Type = Regular;
```

Then in my usercontrol in multiple places I have something like:

```
    if Type ==Advanced
    gridview.DataSource=dataTableAdvanced;
    else if Type==Regular
    gridview.DataSource = dataTableRegular;
```

Or something like:

```
if Type==Advanced
dropdown1.Visible=true
else
dropdown1.Visible=false
```

Control is getting cluttered quickly if I have parameter with, let's say five different values available. Is there a better technique to do this?

Comment: so... which is it, C# or VB.NET that you are programming in?

Comment: @peroija, I'd say it is irrelevant to this particular question, but c#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Advanced control can derive from your Regular control and override a method that sets the dependent objects.

```
class RegularControl
{
   public virtual void SetStuff() { //visible, data source, etc }
}
class AdvancedControl: RegularControl
{
   public override void SetStuff() { // same deal }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you should really have 2 controls, one Advanced and one Regular.

Comment: @user194076: If it were lots of common code, then you wouldn't have lots of If...else statements.  Mike and EricH are right, you might have 2 controls here.  But, you can create a base control which can have some presets..and your regular/advanced control can change only those things that it needs to.